# d3.js-equivalent of jQuery's $(selector).map(fn)

Tags: d3.js

When I want to extract an array of values computed from a d3.js selection, I resort to something like

```
var arr = d3.selectAll(selector)[0].map(fn);
```

...but this feels like "going behind the API" somehow...  Is there anything better?  I.e., something more "official", analogous to jQuery's `$(selector).map(fn)`?

EDIT:

Let me clarify that for this question I'm not interested in solutions based on `d3.selectAll(selector).each(fn)`, with `fn` pushing entries into some pre-existing array.  I'm specifically looking for expressions that *return* an array, not ones that modify an array.

EDIT2:

Alternatively, is there an "official" way to convert a d3.js selection into a standard JS array?

Comment: As I've said in my answer, there's no direct equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery for that, you can use [Javascript's `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) -- in fact it looks like that's what you're using. There's no direct equivalent in D3, but you can emulate it using [`.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each):

```
var arr = [];
d3.selectAll(selector).each(function() { arr.push(fn(this)); });
```